# Login de Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Tengo un código con el cual hago un login por medio de facebook, y es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        xfbml      : true,
         version    : 'v2.6'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function validarUsuario() {  
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
            if(response.status == 'connected') {  
                FB.api('/me', function(response){  
                    alert('Hola ' + response.name);  
                });  
            } else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {  
                    alert('Debes autorizar la app!');  
            } else {  
                alert('Debes ingresar a tu cuenta de Facebook!');  
            }  
        });  
    }  

    function ingresar() {  
        FB.login(function(response){  
            validarUsuario();  
        }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'});  
    }
</script>
```

Y la llamada a la función "ingresar" la hago con el siguiente botón:

```
<div id="IngresaFacebook" onclick="ingresar()"></div>
```

Mi duda es la siguiente:

No tengo idea de como obtener los datos del scope. Solo pude obtener el nombre con "response.name", pero no se como hacer para conseguir el email. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar con esto? Gracias!

Comment: Prueba este explorador del API Graph https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
    console.log('Me alegro de verte, ' + response.email + '.');
    alert('Me alegro de verte, ' + response.email + '.');
});
```

> Permite acceder a la dirección principal de correo electrónico de la persona mediante la propiedad email del objeto user.
>
> ...
>
> Ten en cuenta que solicitar el permiso email no garantiza que obtengas una dirección de correo electrónico. Por ejemplo, si un usuario inicia sesión en Facebook con un número de teléfono en vez de con una dirección de correo electrónico, este campo podría estar vacío.

[Referencia - Facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email)

Comment: La perfecta solución a mi problemática. Muchas gracias!

Comment: P.D.: Si quiero obtener el ID de facebook del usuario, ¿solo escribo "response.id" y ya está?

Comment: Preguntaba porque había leido "por ahí" que ya no se podría pedir el id de usuario de facebook. Sin embargo ya lo probé ayer y funcionó perfecto. Bueno, gracias de nuevo.